# missing distinct alias after distinct with skip and take typeorm

Tags: postgresql, distinct, typeorm

There is a view **mwRightExpired** ->

```
@ObjectType()
@ViewEntity({
  name: 'mw_right_expired',
  expression: `
SELECT
    (mw_right.deposit_expire_date::text) as expire_date,
    mw_right.contract_id as "id",
    mw_right.year as "year",
    CASE
        when MIN(mw_right.latter_half::int) <> MAX(mw_right.latter_half::int) THEN '全体'
        when MIN(mw_right.latter_half::int) = 1 THEN '後半'
        else '前半'
    END as deposit_type
FROM mw_right
WHERE mw_right.deposit_at IS NOT NULL
  AND mw_right.exchanged_at IS NULL
  AND mw_right.revoked_at IS NULL
GROUP BY mw_right.year, mw_right.deposit_expire_date, mw_right.contract_id
`})
export class MwRightExpired {

  @Field(() => Int)
  @ViewColumn({ name: 'id' })
  contractId: number;

  @Field(() => Contract)
  @OneToOne(() => Contract)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'id' })
  contract: Contract;

  @Field(() => DateString)
  @ViewColumn({ name: 'expire_date' })
  expireDate: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @ViewColumn({ name: 'deposit_type' })
  depositType: string;

  @Field(() => Int)
  @ViewColumn({ name: 'year' })
  year: number;

}
```

So I want to add a pagination with `skip` and `take`.. but query is not adding `distinct alias`, so it's output wrong query. So `queryBuilder` is

```
    const queryBuilder = manager.createQueryBuilder(MwRightExpired, 'mwRightExpired')
            .innerJoinAndSelect('mwRightExpired.contract', 'contract')
            .innerJoinAndSelect('contract.client', 'client')
            .where('mwRightExpired.expireDate BETWEEN :fromDate AND :toDate', { fromDate, toDate })
            .skip(0)
            .take(2)
            .getMany();
```

and output is ->

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT 
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
            "mwRightExpired"."id" AS "mwRightExpired_id", "mwRightExpired"."expire_date" AS "mwRightExpired_expire_date", 
            "mwRightExpired"."deposit_type" AS "mwRightExpired_deposit_type", "mwRightExpired"."year" AS "mwRightExpired_year", "contract"."id" AS "contract_id", 
        ..... another selections ...... 
        FROM "mw_right_expired" "mwRightExpired"  
        INNER JOIN "contract" "contract" ON "contract"."id"="mwRightExpired"."id" AND ("contract"."deleted_at" IS NULL)  
        INNER JOIN "client" "client" ON "client"."id"="contract"."client_id" AND ("client"."deleted_at" IS NULL) 
        WHERE "mwRightExpired"."expire_date" BETWEEN '2021-10-01' AND '2021-10-31') "distinctAlias" 
    LIMIT 2
```

So output should something like this ->

```
SELECT 
        DISTINCT "distinctAlias"."mwRightExpired_id"
        FROM 
            (.....) "distinctAlias" 
        LIMIT 2
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue, I believe it's because the model doesn't have a primary_keys which Typeorm uses to build the distinct query. (It works when not joining on any relation though)

Comment: @astreal due to this is not difficult query, it works with limit, offset, instead of take and skip